# How do I print a two digit number with a leading zero?

Tags: c#

I need to print in the pattern 00:00:00 number of hours, minutes and seconds.
I have tried to do it with string format but it just doesn't work

Comment: `someDateTime.ToString("hh:mm:ss")`? What doesn't work, how? What does it print?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ToString` formatting option.

Writing:

```
Console.WriteLine(3.ToString("000"));
Console.WriteLine(34.ToString("000"));
Console.WriteLine(345.ToString("000"));
Console.WriteLine(3456.ToString("000"));
```

Will print:

```
003
034
345
3456
```

So if you've got your hours, minutes and seconds you can do:

```
Console.WriteLine(hours.ToString("00") + ":" + minutes.ToString("00") + ":" + seconds.ToString("00"));
```

Or using string interpolation:

```
Console.WriteLine($"{hours.ToString("00")}:{minutes.ToString("00")}:{seconds.ToString("00")}");
```

You can read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-1.1/0c899ak8(v=vs.71)).

Comment: The question is about leading zeroes. I gave the tool for printing an int with leading zeroes. I think it's not too hard to figure out how to use that for this particular problem.
But whatever, I edited the answer to give a concrete solution now.

Comment: That's better, but we still have no clue whether the OP has 3 ints, a TimeSpan, a DateTime, any of those as `Nullable<T>`. Try to avoid answering questions that lack enough details -- for your own sake

Comment: You can substitute anything for `hours`, `minutes` and `seconds`. Whatever the input is, you can get these values from it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `D` format option:

```
Console.WriteLine($"{hours:D2}:{minutes:D2}:{seconds:D2}");
```